# what is the preferred output structure to generate HTML of multilevel nested content?

Tags: html, windows

I need to generate many parent-children related HTML files representing multilevel content (from a graph of nodes in this case), but I don't know the best output structure to create.

I can imagine the next options:

1. Generate all nodes (HTML files) into a single MHTML file. Problem: I've read that this format is not very "standard", requiring extension to browsers.
2. Generate a directory structure, where each dir will containt its node HTML file plus dirs with the children nodes. Problem: Maybe a lot of directories will be created and could become a mess for the user.
3. Generate a directory structure, like in point 2, but inside a .ZIP file. Problem: Not directly viewable by a web browser.
4. Generate a single directory with all the HTML files at the same level, but renamed to avoid same-name clashes (like "node15atlevel1.node38atlevel2.node74atlevel3.html"). Problem: File names could become too long due to deep nested containment.
5. Generate files in the same directory, like in point 4, but using short coded file names (like "n015038074.html" instead of "node15atlevel1.node38atlevel2.node74atlevel3.html".

So, what do you think? what is the most practical and viable way to output nested content as HTML?

Thanks!

Comment: If you look at the URL here: http://demo.phpdoc.org/Responsive/classes/phpDocumentor.Plugin.Core.Transformer.Behaviour.Tag.AuthorTag.html, see how it's got `classes/phpDocumentor.Plugin.Core.Transformer.Behaviour.Tag.AuthorTag.html`? If you look on that page, you'll see the breadcrumbs at the top. I'd think about something along these lines, with a naming construct describing the file structures. And then author a loading script from your directory file listing (or use a loader like phpDocumentor) to read all file names in and parse the names into a structure to navigate.

Comment: Yeah, Jared, what you say is like option 4. It's the second favorite.